# Conditionally add an item to an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, conditional-statements

I'm trying to figure out how to add an item to an array based on the return value of a method.

Something like where in a method you can do `return array.contains(value)` and automatically return a boolean, but in a way where you can, instead of returning that value, add it to an array?

Is this possible in the same format, where you don't need a conditional statement?

Sorry for the noonish question, and thanks for the help!

Comment: If you don't want to `return` something, then why not just use a conditional statement? What do you mean?

Comment: You could work with streams. e.g. to take all numbers from array1 that are bigger than 5 and put them into array2 you could write `int[] array2 = Arrays.stream(array1).filter(n -> n > 5).toArray()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you mean is this:

```
if(array.contains(value)){
    array2.add(value)
}
```

Comment: Yeah - This is what I had, I was just curious if it could be done in one line or not... thanks!